# Can I use Scrapy without the calling a spider?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I've installed scrapy and following the scrapy tutorial from the website. I notice that you need to create a spider and then call the spider in order to use it. I was thinking: can i use scrapy commands in a normal python script (in the IDLE)?

Comment: Of course you can. Why not? Have you tried it?

Comment: @bakka i haven't tried it because I can't find anything about it. I only find examples of using spiders via a terminal.

Comment: One of the great features of Python is that one can explore the use of a module interactively and then use the same statements in a script.  The main difference is having to add `print()` around expressions to see results.  IDLE and other IDEs do not change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@seppukki, recently I tried a similar approach using the `CrawlerProcess` library. I was successful. A minimum reprex is shown below. You can view the notebook [here](https://github.com/duttashi/scrapers/blob/master/src/python/scrapy%20framework%20based%20scrapers/scrapy_notebook_00.ipynb). Essentially the following code snippet will crawl the webpage, extract the content and write it to a file. I do not have to execute `scrapy` commands in terminal.

```
# import scrapy
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

# Set up a pipeline
import json

class JsonWriterPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('results\\quoteresult.txt', 'w+')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
# Define the spider
import logging

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        'LOG_LEVEL': logging.WARNING,
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'__main__.JsonWriterPipeline': 1}, # Used for pipeline 1
        'FEED_FORMAT':'json',                                 # Used for pipeline 2
        'FEED_URI': 'quoteresult.json'                        # Used for pipeline 2
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first(),
                'author': quote.css('span small::text').extract_first(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract(),
            }
# Start the crawl
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(QuotesSpider)
process.start()

2018-09-22 18:07:39 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2018-09-22 18:07:39 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.4.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
2018-09-22 18:07:39 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'FEED_URI': 'quoteresult.json', 'LOG_LEVEL': 30, 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'}
```

Comment: But can't you just import the libraries and do all the response parsing yourself kind of like you do on the scrapy shell? without the need for Crawlers, Spiders and yield.